# Opening a port on a client PC connected to Win Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a port 12345 on a client PC, connected to a switch, connected to Server 2008, connected to Uverse Modem/Router for internet. 
I need to allow incoming requests to that port (forward/open).

I have the port number open on both the router and the server but it's still not allowing connections.

If the client is connected directly to the router then the port is open but cannot figure the block when connected thru the server. HELP Please

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your windows 2008, go to routing and remote access, go to IPV4, NAT, select the external network adapter, right click, properties.

Go to the third tab (ports and services) click add give a name to it

Set:

TCP

incoming port: 12345

private address: your pc local ip address

port 12345